# Checking if string value is a set of integers

Tags: java

I am trying to take in a String and check if the values of the string are equal to numbers between 1-9999 and return an error message otherwise. I have seen and heard that I can use .isNumeric() or .Matches() but I can't seem to figure out how to implement it. This is what I have so far:

```
String yearString;
int year = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    System.out.println("Please enter the year of the start date");
    yearString = input.nextLine();

    if (yearString.matches("[1-9999]+"))
    {
        year = Integer.parseInt(yearString);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter positive numbers only");
    }

} while (year <= 0);
```

Comment: And what is the specific question you have?

Comment: Your regex generates at least all `[1-10]+` expressions, which is almost all integers (some integers with zeros cannot be expressed like this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a regex approach, you can use the following regex instead of `[1-9999]+` (which generates infinite numbers) : `[1-9][0-9]{0,3}`. This means *any `String` starting with a non-zero figure followed by 3 or less figures.*

A little test :

```
String regex = "[1-9][0-9]{0,3}";
int i;
for (i=0 ; String.valueOf(i + 1).matches(regex) ; i++);
System.out.println(i);
```

Outputs `9999` as expected. However, **@uʍop ǝpısdn** solution is more readable but may be slower if there are a lot of invalid strings (exception have a non negligeable cost) whereas the regex approach does not depend of this. If you have a lot of entries to test, you should compile your pattern only once and use a `Matcher` :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[1-9][0-9]{0,3}"); 
int i;
for (i=0 ; p.matcher(String.valueOf(i + 1)).matches() ; i++);
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Let's say instead of a number between 1-9999 i was looking for a number between 1-24. I was able to change it to other numbers but as soon as i need the second number to only go between 0-4 i get stumped

Comment: That's another disadvantage of the regex approach : it is harder to automatize if you want a different range. For 1-24, you could do : `1[0-9]?|2[0-4]?|[3-9]`. I don't know if something simpler is possible, but you can see that this approach can become complicated if you need flexibility

Comment: I can see how this can become complicated. I just have not been taught try and catch yet so i don't want to implement it yet

Comment: Also, could you explain the format of regex? I am having trouble creating a one from 1-31

Comment: A number between 1 and 31 can be any number between 1 and 9 or a two-digits number starting with 1, 2 or 3. If it starts with 1 or 2, the second digits can be any digit (0-9). Otherwise, the second digit can only be 0 or 1. With that logic you can build your regex, if you have any problem with the syntax, check this link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 2):

This expression:

```
[1-9999]+
```

Means "match a number from 1 to 9, or a 9, or a 9, or a 9". Each 9 is taken separately.

You can correct that regex, but it's easier to conver the number to an integer and check for its validity afterwards.

```
boolean isValid(String numericString) {
    try {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(numericString);
        return number > 0 && number <= 9999;

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not overly confident with the try and catch is it possible to do this without a try and catch?

Comment: No. If you don't `catch` the exception, it means the the user of this function will have to. You want to keep the error contained, since it originates here and makes no sense outside.